# SQL Server : how would I find overlaps in visits within my unique key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a system that is creating records within a table based on both unique key and primary key. Each visit is assigned to a client's unique key, and should be creating a primary key for every visit. However in some cases the system is creating multiple primary keys for the same visit. How would I go about finding those clients to which this is happening?

Here is a data sample that should recreate the issue.

```
RecordNum   ClientNum   VisitDate
---------------------------------
12345       B1000       8/15/2015
12345       B1001       8/20/2015
12345       B1002       8/20/2015
13456       C1000       9/23/2014
13456       C1001       9/24/2015
13456       C1002       10/2/2015
13456       C1003       10/2/2015
13456       C1004       10/2/2015
15165       D1000       11/1/2015
15165       D1001       11/2/2015
15165       D1002       11/3/2015
15165       D1003       11/4/2015
15165       D1004       11/5/2015
15165       D1005       11/6/2015
```

Obviously I can also use some advice on how to format data sets, I apologize in advance.

Comment: is recordnum supposed to be unqiue? or the combination of recordnum and clientnum?

Comment: Please explain the output you want.

Comment: Not clear at all.   Every row has a unique ClientNum and VisitDate, so what do you mean there are multiple PKs for the same visit?

Comment: I would like to see which clientnum's within a record have the same VisitDate.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want `RecordNum` to be unique based on `ClientNum` and `VisitDate`.  You can find anomalies using something like this:

```
select recordnum
from t
group by recordnum
having count(distinct clientnum) > 0 or count(distinct visitdate < 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientNum, VisitDate
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY (ClientNum + CAST(VisitDate as varchar(20)))
HAVING COUNT (ClientNum + CAST(VisitDate as varchar(20))) > 1
```

Comment: What on earth is this concatenation for? Use `GROUP BY ClientNum, VisitDate)` instead!